# Regular expression to replace part of URL

Tags: regex, url

I have over 5000 lines like so:

```
www.example.com/de/germany/germany-company-domaincheck
www.example.com/de/germany/germany-company-question
www.example.com/de/germany/index
www.example.com/de/germany-page
www.example.com/de/france/france-company-domaincheck
www.example.com/de/france/france-company-question
www.example.com/de/france/index
www.example.com/de/france/france-page
```

I need to replace:

```
www.example.com/de/germany/germany-company-domaincheck
www.example.com/de/france/france-company-domaincheck
etc
```

With

```
www.example.com/de/enquiry
```

Unfortunately I am useless at regular expressions and don't know where to start. Using sublime text what is the correct regular expression to find all occurrences of /?/?-company-domaincheck

Comment: Getting from zero to a point where you can match `/?/?-company-domaincheck` with regular expressions would take you a few hours of reading introduction level how-tos ***at most***. So this question is basically telling us that you don't want to do that. That's ... not a good starting point, really.

Answer (score 2):

The regex

```
/(www\.example\.com)(\/\w+){3}(-company-domaincheck)/g
```

will match any of

```
www.example.com/?/?/?-company-domaincheck
```

(assuming that `?` only contains [A-Za-z]), as in your examples.

To match another number of folders in between, replace `{3}` by the desired number (or by `+` for any).

Comment: You need to escape the dots. And the parens are unnecessary except for the repeated group.

Comment: +1 for "escape dots". Thanks, edited my answer.
Although parentheses are unnecessary, they make the regex look more clean (in my point of view).